# Simulate a CNAME removal from DNS on local computer

Tags: dns, unc, cname

My company is going to deleting a CNAME record from DNS and replacing it with a new record "\\OLDCNAME\Apps" to "\\NEWCNAME\Apps".  Currently both are existing values on the network and they both point to the same set of files and folders.  We are currently trying to update configuration files (.properties, .ini, .xml) that has any references to OLDCNAME to utilize the new CNAME and test the applications to see if they are working correctly.

Is there a way to simulate the delete of OLDCNAME on a local computer to enable us to test the applications before the company deletes the old CNAME record from DNS?

Thanks

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to add the old hostname to your local HOSTS file with an IP address of 127.0.0.1. I’m not sure where CNAMEs are coming in to this. The server has a hostname that is in DNS (an A record). There is an old method of using cnames for secondary server names, but that method is obsolete. Secondary server names are added/removed with the `netdom computername` command and that results in additional A records (and other resource records). That is called a server alias. Not CNAME records. Finally, what you are listing in your question is a UNC path.

Comment: Minimal install of Linux and Bind9, set up your zone sans old cname record, and point a client machine to it as a DNS source.

Comment: Thank you for the comments OLDCNAME used to be a name of a server.  That server was decommissioned and replaced with a NAS.  The server group added a record so that we can continue to use OLDCNAME when accessing configuration files and mapping drives, now they are taking away that record (whether it is a CNAME record or and A record).  I believe someone tried the local hosts file before but I can try again to see if that works for me.